# webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; orientation change issue

Tags: html, ios, css, scroll, mobile-safari

Okay, so I have a fixed position div that has a specified width. When the content is long enough to require overflow in one device orientation (landscape), but not the other (portrait) scrolling stops working if the device changes orientation.

This issue occurs with iOS7 (unable to test previous versions)

Here is the address of the example: https://r3dux.com/css/overflow.php

Here is an illustration of the issue:

[image: overflow issue]

Comment: Yes, I tested it in iOS7 and iOS6 and both worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Weird, I've tested it in iOS simulator, on my iPhone, and iPad (with more content) and it stops working when orientation is changed.

Comment: Maybe go into Safari and change your User Agent to an iOS device User Agent and see if it works properly.

Comment: It works fine on desktop safari... that's not the issue. I not sure I see how changing the user agent will affect a browser's behavior like that.

Comment: Apparently if you redraw the div on orientation change it works again. (toggle display: block; to display: none; and back to display: block;) - really annoyed that this is needed.

Comment: I'm surprised that you need that.

Comment: Mobile Safari tries really hard to minimize triggering reflows. Since iOS 5 when they added `overflow-scrolling`, there's always been some quirk about how that feature works. To be honest, the fact that you need to toggle the display doesn't surprise. You're forcing the browser to reflow. In the past, I use to set `padding-left` to the body and then remove it after 50ms or so. That might also work (and the experience may not be as jarring as setting display to none)

Comment: I have a 10ms delay before returning the display to normal. It isn't really noticeable as it occurs during the orientation change quickly, and safari already does weird stuff during that.

Comment: ugh... now I'm having an issue with it the overflow-scroll element not respecting z-index of elements on top of it. WTF Apple. :(

Comment: I currently have the same problem. iOS (only when the app is saved and started from the home screen) is ignoring z-index order of elements (element below is scrolled). Also after I change the orientation of the device it works as expected, even after switching back.
Did you find a solution to this problem? (the padding-bottom one does not solve this)

Answer (score 7):

I fixed that problem with CSS.

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) {
 .webkit-scroll-container > * {
   -webkit-animation: fixWebkitOverflowScroll 1s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes fixWebkitOverflowScroll {
   0% {
     padding-bottom: 1px;
   }
   100% {
     padding-bottom: 0px;
   }
 }
}
```

Just put it inside your stylesheet, assign the class `.webkit-scroll-container` and everything will work as expected. I just animate the height, which triggers a reflow/redraw of the scroll container.

Comment: does this fix the ovelaying issue? (if the is a div over the fixed div, the scrolling goes to the fixed div)

Comment: Assume something like that: <div class="scroll" style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"><div class=".content">Your actual content</div></div>